Is there a way to compile SPIR-V to HLSL?
I'm currently writing a small game engine for fun, but I can't seem to find a SPIR-V (Vulkan) to HLSL library, Am I just stupid or does this thing not exist? If it doesn't would it be viable to make one?
Searched the internet, all I can find is Cross-SPIRV.

You're thinking of a transpiler or source-to-source compiler. This would essentially be the same as saying, is there a "C++ to Java transpiler?". There likely are attempts, but they are likely limited in what they support

What do you need it for? Maybe you're thinking about it the wrong way?

I'm doing a full rewrite of the rendering as when I wrote the rendering I was quite bad at writing rendering code. Currently I'm working on the DirectX portion, but I've been wondering if I could allow myself to just write SPIR-V when using the engine and have it converted to HLSL so it works with the DirectX renderer on Windows.
